# How to group a pandas timeseries index into groups with the same frequency?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, time-series

I have a timeseries with sub-sequences of the same timedelta between rows, but this timedelta is not the same between all sub-sequences.

```
series
>>>
timestamp
2018-06-12 08:01:00    0.5456   # minute intervals
2018-06-12 08:02:00    0.4734
2018-06-12 08:03:00    0.6723
...
2018-09-12 15:00:00    1.2449   # hour intervals
2018-09-12 16:00:00    1.2834
2018-09-12 17:00:00    1.4923
```

Is it possible to group this series into chunks with the same timedelata? The ideal output would be some sort of list of series, each with the same timedelta and no overlap between series.

```
desired_output
>>> [
# series 1
timestamp
2018-06-12 08:01:00    0.5456   # minute intervals
2018-06-12 08:02:00    0.4734
2018-06-12 08:03:00    0.6723
...
,
# series 2
2018-09-12 15:00:00    1.2449   # hour intervals
2018-09-12 16:00:00    1.2834
2018-09-12 17:00:00    1.4923
...
,
# so on
]
```

I've looked at the [pandas Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) function, although I couldnt find any methods that did this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) to create a new column with time deltas, and the use the pandas `groupby`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Dummy data
data=[0.45,0.47,0.62,1.21,1.21,0.21,2.54,3.45,4.12,2.01,2.1]
id1 = pd.date_range(start='2018-06-12 08:01:00', periods=6, freq='T')
id2 = pd.date_range(start='2018-06-12 08:06:00', periods=6, freq='H')
join_index = id1.union(id2)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index = join_index

# Create a column with the time delta
df['deltaT'] = np.append(np.diff(df.index.values) , np.diff(df.index.values)[-1])

# Group by the latter
grouper = df.groupby(by='deltaT')

Series_freq = []
for name , group in grouper:
    Series_freq.append(group)
print(Series_freq)
```

outputs:

```py
[                        0          deltaT
 2018-06-12 08:01:00  0.45 0 days 00:01:00
 2018-06-12 08:02:00  0.47 0 days 00:01:00
 2018-06-12 08:03:00  0.62 0 days 00:01:00
 2018-06-12 08:04:00  1.21 0 days 00:01:00
 2018-06-12 08:05:00  1.21 0 days 00:01:00,
                         0          deltaT
 2018-06-12 08:06:00  0.21 0 days 01:00:00
 2018-06-12 09:06:00  2.54 0 days 01:00:00
 2018-06-12 10:06:00  3.45 0 days 01:00:00
 2018-06-12 11:06:00  4.12 0 days 01:00:00
 2018-06-12 12:06:00  2.01 0 days 01:00:00
 2018-06-12 13:06:00  2.10 0 days 01:00:00]
```

This is not perfect, as i'm not sure how to handle the row that is just at the frequency change... in this case the `2018-06-12 08:06:00` index should be included in both Series, the first, the second ?